# windows mobile application development Windows 7 Operating System

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I have to develop a mobile application for windows mobile and NOT windows phone.

I am trying to initialize the development environment in Windows 7 OS 32/64 bit.

I searched the web for environment initialization.

Please let me know the environment initialization procedure for Windows mobile application develoopment in Windows 7 32/64 bit from scratch.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the question.

I had to do nothing special as I installed Visual Studio 2008 and then the Windows Mobile 6 SDK.

I assume, you already connected the WM device to your Win7 station. So you should have WMDC already installed. Otherwise install Windows Mobile Device Center from the MS site.

Secondly install VS2008 (not express version, it does not support WM development).

Then download and install Windows Mobile 6 (professionell) SDK and install.

That is all, nothing special. I did it without any hassle on my Win7/64 PC. Should be the same for Win7/32.

If you need further assistance be more specific in your description.

Comment: Hi josef. I setup the environment by additionally installing the Visual Studio 2008 service pack1. Then it installed properly.Thanks for the time and help